# Can FTRL be applied on linear least squares? or is it just for logistic regression models?

Tags: logistic-regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent, online-learning

I'm exploring follow-the-regularized-leader FTRL proximal gradient descent:
[paper](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/papers/ad-click-prediction.pdf), [reference implementation](https://github.com/mlandry22/kaggle/blob/master/modern_logistic_regression/fast_solution_v3.py).

Everywhere FTRL is mentioned, the loss surface for the gradient decent is the `LogLoss`, and the model for prediction is `Logistic regression`.

Can I use the same algorithm for a linear least squares model? I have a problem I want to model with a `linear model` and define the loss by `least squares`, and then do FTRL to find the optimal solution - do you see any problem with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see, FTRL is nothing to do with our model, and it only serves as a way of approximating the optimal solution , just as SGD does.

Logloss is just a kind of loss pattern in classification problem,and there are other alternatives for it , such as ExpLoss. Least-squres loss is one of all loss patterns in regression problem.

The reason why FTRL was mentioned everywhere ,which mainly treated Logloss as a example, is that it was often used in classification problem , such as CTR model in online advertisement scenario.

Hopes this can helps you ,and good luck !